# Unicode encoding for string literals in C++11

Tags: c++, unicode, c++11, utf, string-literals

Following a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794590/how-does-file-encoding-affect-c11-string-literals), I'd like to ask about the new character and string literal types in C++11. It seems that we now have four sorts of characters and five sorts of string literals. The character types:

```
char     a =  '\x30';         // character, no semantics
wchar_t  b = L'\xFFEF';       // wide character, no semantics
char16_t c = u'\u00F6';       // 16-bit, assumed UTF16?
char32_t d = U'\U0010FFFF';   // 32-bit, assumed UCS-4
```

And the string literals:

```
char     A[] =  "Hello\x0A";         // byte string, "narrow encoding"
wchar_t  B[] = L"Hell\xF6\x0A";      // wide string, impl-def'd encoding
char16_t C[] = u"Hell\u00F6";        // (1)
char32_t D[] = U"Hell\U000000F6\U0010FFFF"; // (2)
auto     E[] = u8"\u00F6\U0010FFFF"; // (3)
```

The question is this: Are the `\x`/`\u`/`\U` character references freely combinable with all string types? Are all the string types fixed-width, i.e. the arrays contain precisely as many elements as appear in the literal, or to `\x`/`\u`/`\U` references get expanded into a variable number of bytes? Do `u""` and `u8""` strings have encoding semantics, e.g. can I say `char16_t x[] = u"\U0010FFFF"`, and the non-BMP codepoint gets encoded into a two-unit UTF16 sequence? And similarly for `u8`? In (1), can I write lone surrogates with `\u`? Finally, are any of the string functions encoding aware (i.e. they are character-aware and can detect invalid byte sequences)?

This is a bit of an open-ended question, but I'd like to get as complete a picture as possible of the new UTF-encoding and type facilities of the new C++11.

Comment: GCC does encode `u"\U0010FFFF"` into a surrogate pair.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> Are the \x/\u/\U character references freely combinable with all string types?

No. `\x` can be used in anything, but `\u` and `\U` can only be used in strings that are specifically UTF-encoded. However, for any UTF-encoded string, `\u` and `\U` can be used as you see fit.

> Are all the string types fixed-width, i.e. the arrays contain precisely as many elements as appear in the literal, or to \x/\u/\U references get expanded into a variable number of bytes?

Not in the way you mean. `\x`, `\u`, and `\U` are converted based on the string encoding. The number of those "code units" (using Unicode terms. A `char16_t` is a UTF-16 code unit) values depends on the encoding of the containing string. The literal `u8"\u1024"` would create a string containing 2 `char`s plus a null terminator. The literal `u"\u1024"` would create a string containing 1 `char16_t` plus a null terminator.

The number of code units used is based on the Unicode encoding.

> Do u"" and u8"" strings have encoding semantics, e.g. can I say char16_t x[] = u"\U0010FFFF", and the non-BMP codepoint gets encoded into a two-unit UTF16 sequence?

`u""` creates a UTF-16 encoded string. `u8""` creates a UTF-8 encoded string. They will be encoded per the Unicode specification.

> In (1), can I write lone surrogates with \u?

Absolutely not. The specification expressly forbids using the UTF-16 surrogate pairs (0xD800-0xDFFF) as codepoints for `\u` or `\U`.

> Finally, are any of the string functions encoding aware (i.e. they are character-aware and can detect invalid byte sequences)?

Absolutely not. Well, allow me to rephrase that.

`std::basic_string` doesn't deal with Unicode encodings. They certainly can *store* UTF-encoded strings. But they can only think of them as sequences of `char`, `char16_t`, or `char32_t`; they can't think of them as a sequence of Unicode codepoints that are encoded with a particular mechanism. `basic_string::length()` will return the number of code units, not code points. And obviously, the C standard library string functions are totally useless

It should be noted however that "length" for a Unicode string does not mean the number of codepoints. Some code points are combining "characters" (an unfortunate name), which combine with the previous codepoint. So multiple codepoints can map to a single visual character.

Iostreams can in fact read/write Unicode-encoded values. To do so, you will have to use a locale to specify the encoding and properly imbue it into the various places. This is easier said than done, and I don't have any code on me to show you how.

Comment: @Philipp: [No, they are not.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates) Unicode specifically reserves them for UTF-16 surrogates. And, as stated, C++0x's specification says that compilation will fail if you try to designate a code point in that range.

Comment: Your link proves that they *are* code points. If you don't trust Wikipedia, read definitions 9 and 10 in chapter 3 of the Standard. Surrogate code points in string literals are forbidden in C++0x by rule § 2.4/2, though.

Comment: After reading I confirm too that Surrogate code points are accepted in string literals.

Comment: In C11, `\x` can not be used with anything, for example U+1F984 will not work with the \x prefix, and `\u` and `\U` can not be used with ASCII control characters, atleast in Clang.