# What are the automatic type promotions of variadic function arguments?

Tags: c, runtime-error, variadic-functions

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void display(int num, ...) {
    char c;
    int j;
    va_list ptr;
    va_start(ptr,num);
    for (j= 1; j <= num; j++){
        c = va_arg(ptr, char);
        printf("%c", c);

    }
    va_end(ptr);
}

int main() {
    display(4, 'A', 'a', 'b', 'c');
    return 0;
}
```

The program gives runtime error because vararg automatically promotes char to int, and i should have used int in this case.

What are all types are permitted when I use vararg, how to know which type to use and avoid such runtime errors.

Comment: Hehe, GCC says, "warning: ‘char’ is promoted to ‘int’ when passed through ‘...’". Nice.

Comment: In `display(4, 'A', 'a', 'b', 'c');` there are 5 `int`s; not 1 `int` and 4 `char`s as you seem to believe :)

Comment: @Kerrek: it says that for the expression `va_arg(ptr, char)`, not the call to the `display` function -- where there are no `char`s :)

Comment: @pmg: Ah, indeed -- that's one of the changes from C to C++: in C char literals are integers... I never knew you couldn't use chars variadically. `wchar_t` also doesn't work, and neither do `char16_t` or `char32_t` (they're all promoted to `unsigned int`).

Comment: This probably depends on the compiler / machine word length. You could even redefine va_arg to take account of this.

Comment: @Kerrek - What is this `char16_t` you speak of?

Comment: @Chris: A new type in C++11, and probably in C1x. Good for UTF16 strings :-) (E.g. [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c0x).)

Comment: @Kerrek - They are being added to C1x. Good to know.

Comment: @QuentinUK - How could you (portably) redefine `va_arg`? And how would it take the standard promotions into account?

Answer (score 10):

another case that the others forgot to mention are pointer types, critical is `NULL` in particular. Since this could expand to `0` or `(void*)0` (or some other weird things) you will not know if the compiler puts an `int` or a `void*` in the list. Since these can have different width, this can lead to annoying bugs.

Comment: Yep, that's always a subtle source of bugs.  GCC is nice and expands `NULL` to `__nullptr` instead of `0`, so you won't run into that bug with GCC, but other compilers are not so nice.  The C standard only requires that `NULL` expand to an "implementation-defined null pointer constant", which is "an integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void*`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use any standard type with `va_arg` except `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `short`, `unsigned short`, `_Bool`, and `float`. It's possible that an implementation defines additional nonstandard types that also have integer conversion rank lower than `int`, or likewise nonstandard small floating-point types, but you would not need to be aware of these unless you intend to use them, so for practical purposes the list I gave is complete.

Answer (score 1):

While using va_arg the `char` is promoted to `int`. There are other types(the list given by @R..) which are promoted.

so in order to read it as a `char` you have to do typecast.

```c
char c = (char) va_arg(ap, int);
```

For a complete list, please see the 'Default conversions' section in:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments