# Determining argument size in variadic functions

Tags: c, x86, variadic-functions

I'm implementing a `printk` function for my toy OS kernel targeting x86 platform. If I call `printk` like this:

```
uint64_t x = 0xdead;
uint64_t z = 0xbeef;
printk("%p %s\n", x & z, "yes");
```

that is, passing a 64-bit integer (`x & z`) to it, then the generated assembly code would be:

```
c01000bd:       c7 45 f0 ad de 00 00    movl   $0xdead,-0x10(%ebp)
c01000c4:       c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
c01000cb:       c7 45 e8 ef be 00 00    movl   $0xbeef,-0x18(%ebp)
c01000d2:       c7 45 ec 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x14(%ebp)
c01000d9:       8b 45 f0                mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
c01000dc:       23 45 e8                and    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
c01000df:       89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
c01000e1:       8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
c01000e4:       23 45 ec                and    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
c01000e7:       89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
c01000e9:       68 e4 17 10 c0          push   $0xc01017e4
c01000ee:       56                      push   %esi
c01000ef:       53                      push   %ebx
c01000f0:       68 e8 17 10 c0          push   $0xc01017e8
c01000f5:       e8 27 0a 00 00          call   c0100b21 <printk>
```

You can see here gcc uses two 32-bit registers (`%esi` and `%ebx`) to store the 64-bit value. The result of this is the number of arguments pushed to the stack becomes 4 instead of 3. If the code inside `printk` cannot figure out the size of the argument and consume it properly, the stack access would be messed up.

So my question is, when implementing a variadic function, how can I know the size of the next argument when I use `va_arg` macro? Or specifically, how to solve this 32-bit-vs-64-bit `printk` problem?

Comment: "how can I know the size of the next argument when I use `va_arg` macro?" You don't need to know the size of the next argument. You need the *type* of the next argument to pass to `va_arg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does not provide a general way to determine the size or type of the arguments.  For `printf` like functions you must rely on the format string.  This is why getting the format string wrong compared to the arguments passed can result in some very buggy code; since you can be reading past the intended arguments if you get the size wrong.  The format string also tells you the number of arguments.

Also another thing to consider is the default argument promotion for variadic functions.  You can find more information about that in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084857/what-are-the-automatic-type-promotions-of-variadic-function-arguments).

Here is an example of what something going back if the format string mismatches the types you pass via the arguments.  You need to compile this on a 32 bit machine or use `gcc -m32 file.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("%u: %s\n", (1ULL << 63), "Hello World");
  return 0;
}
```

So why is this so bad, it looks okay, we have 2 format characters and 2 arguments right?  Well not so fast, for a 32 bit machine `%u` is 32 bits and so is the char pointer.  However (1ULL << 63) is 64 bits long.  So what happens is that 96 bytes are pushed onto the stack (or however arguments are passed).  The format string though is only going to use the first 64.  It also just so happens that the first 32 bits will be all zeros and the second 32 bits, the bits used for the char pointer, have the value (1 << 31).  Since `printf` is expecting a char pointer that value is dereferenced which causes undefined behavior, specifically a segmentation fault on my machine.

Comment: So does it mean that it is entirely the user's responsibility to keep the arguments consistent to the format string, for example, never pass a 64-bit argument to a `%u` format specifier, if he/she doesn't want to get strange problems?

Comment: Yep, I'll try to come up with a simple example of how this can be really bad if you mess this up.

Comment: OK, I think I have got your point, but the example will still be helpful :)

Comment: @PJ.Hades I have added an example let me know if there is any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one of the arguments to determine the size (usually the first argument).  With printf() the size is determined by the format specifiers in the format string.  There's nothing really magical about this.