# Dereferencing char pointer returns int ? why?

Tags: c

For example, the following code returns an error and a warning when compiled and an `int` when changed to `%d`

> Warning:
> format `%s` expects argument of type `char *`, but argument 2 has type `int`

```c
void stringd() {
    char *s = "Hello";
    printf("derefernced s is %s", *s);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `s` is a pointer to the first out of a series of characters which are consecutive in memory (colloquially referred to as a "string", though it's not quite the same). It's a pointer to a character, thus `char *`.

Dereferencing `s` (by doing `*s`) gives you the first of those characters, `h`, whose type is now just `char`. One layer of indirection was stripped away.

Thus, the issue is that you're trying to pass a character (`char`), where a string (`char *`) was expected. `char *` was expected because you used the `%s` type character in your format string to `printf`. Instead, you should use `%c`, which expects single, simple `char`.

The mistake here is actually quite grave. If you were allowed to pass this `'h'` where a `char *` was expected, you would end up with the ASCII code of `'h'` (`0x68`) being passed where a pointer was expected. `printf` would be none-the-wiser, and would try to dereference that value, treating `0x68` like a pointer to the beginning of a string. Of course, that's probably not a valid memory location in your program, so that should seg-fault pretty reliability, if it were allowed to happen.

Answer (score 7):

`*s` is an expression of type char since it's the dereference operator applied to a pointer-to-char<sup>1</sup>. As a result, it gets [promoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084857/what-are-the-automatic-type-promotions-of-variadic-function-arguments) to an int when passed to `printf`; in order to print a null-terminated string, you need to pass the pointer to the first character (i.e. just `s`).

<sup>1</sup> even though `s` is not a const pointer, you should not try to modify the characters it points to as they may be placed in read-only memory where string literals are stored on some architectures/environments; see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4493156/1424875) for more details.