# GNU Gettext and wide characters

Tags: c++, internationalization, gettext, sfml

I'm developing a game (actually I'm porting it from Gosu to SFML) in C++. I'm using GNU Gettext as the i18n system. As you know, gettext returns `char *` strings using the local encoding, usually UTF8. The problem is that I need to use wide strings for SFML to recognize the special characters such as `áéíüñ`.

So the question would be: how do I create a **proper** `wstring` from the output of gettext? It would be great if there were some kind of `wchar_t * w_gettext()` function, but there's not. I have tried some options, such as creating a `wstring` from the original `string` by passing the iterators, but obviously it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert between the system's narrow, multibyte encoding and its wide character set (agnostic of any encoding specifics), use the `mbstowcs()` and `wcstombs()` standard C functions, found in `<cwchar>`. Here's a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) of mine on the subject, and here's some [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141260/compare-stdwstring-and-stdstring/7159944#7159944).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your multi-byte UTF-8 string to wide char.

On Windows, use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx). On Unix, use [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/).