# How to convert string to wstring in C++

Tags: c++, string, wstring

I have programmed some code but there is some problem. In this codes i am trying to convert string to wstring. But this string have "█" characters. This character have 219 ascii code. 
This conversion getting error.

In my code:
`string strs= "█and█something else";
          wstring wstr(strs.begin(),strs.end());`

After debugging, I am getting result like this
 `?and?something else`

How do I correct this problem?

Thanks...

Comment: Here's an old [pre-C++11 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7159944/596781). With C++11 there's a slightly easier way using a built-in codecvt facet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C-library solution for converting between the system's narrow and wide encoding use the `mbsrtowcs` and `wcsrtombs` functions from the `<cwchar>` header. I've spelt this out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7159944/596781).

In C++11, you can use the `wstring_convert` template instantiated with a suitable `codecvt` facet.  Unfortunately this requires some custom rigging, which is spelt out on the [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/wstring_convert).

I've adapted it here into a self-contained example which converts a `wstring` to a `string`, converting from the system's wide into the system's narrow encoding:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

// utility wrapper to adapt locale-bound facets for wstring/wbuffer convert
template <typename Facet>
struct deletable_facet : Facet
{
    using Facet::Facet;
};

int main()
{
    std::wstring_convert<
        deletable_facet<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>>> conv;

    std::wstring ws(L"Hello world.");
    std::string ns = conv.to_bytes(ws);

    std::cout << ns << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for interesting. But I must convert string to wstring. I not sure that Is Your code convert string to wstring. I may try to this code.

Comment: @Mehmet: Look up the documentation. `to_bytes` and `from_bytes`.