# string to wstring - prevent conversion from stopping on \0

Tags: c++, c, string, type-conversion, wstring

So I have `string` variable that I want to convert to `wstring`.

I'm using [mbstowcs_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyktyxsx.aspx).

Unfortunately my `string` variable contain `\0` as a character (does not mark the end of the string) and has documented:

*The mbstowcs_s function converts a string of multibyte characters pointed to 
by mbstr into wide characters stored in the buffer pointed to by wcstr. 
The conversion will continue for each character until one of these conditions is met:
**A multibyte null character is encountered***

My temporary solution is to convert char by char. that solves the issue but unfortunately deteriorates performance drastically.

Any idea how to overcome that? must I use different function for conversion?

Comment: [Maybe useful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25485477/596781)

Comment: Please do not post [duplicates of your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571564/mbstowcs-s-stops-conversion-if-multibyte-null-character-is-encountered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `MultiByteToWideChar` which allows you to specify the number of chars to convert.

```
int MultiByteToWideChar(
  _In_       UINT CodePage,
  _In_       DWORD dwFlags,
  _In_       LPCSTR lpMultiByteStr,
  _In_       int cbMultiByte,
  _Out_opt_  LPWSTR lpWideCharStr,
  _In_       int cchWideChar
);
```

See [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072.aspx) function.

However, `MultiByteToWideChar` is Win32 API, but that should be no problem in your case.

IIRC `mbstowcs` also calls `MultiByteToWideChar`.

Comment: if `mbstowcs` also calls `MultiByteToWideChar`, do they deliberately call `MultiByteToWideChar` in such way the they stop on `\0`?

Comment: If you call `MultiByteToWideChar` with cbMultiByte=-1 it will also stop on `\0` and that's what `mbstowcs` might do.