# Assert a BSTR with string

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, assert

I have a test function as follow:

```
    [TestMethod]
    void RipMichaelJacksonTest()
    {
        string expected = "Hello";
        BSTR actual = SysAllocString(L"Hello");
        Assert::AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

The `assert` part will of course fail.

Is there any Assert function that i can use?
Im new to VC++.

Comment: Well, the strings are not equal.

Comment: Question is not clear. "Is there any Assert function that i can use?" You are already using one.

Comment: @user1 that `Assert` is not correct. `Assert::AreEqual` is not able to take a `BSTR` as a parameter

Comment: This this C++/CLR? If so you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing a [`AreEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal.aspx). Passing in two parameters will force [`AreEqual(Object^, Object^)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243413.aspx) which:

> Verifies that two specified objects are equal. The assertion fails if the objects are not equal.

What you are actually looking for is the comparison of a `wchar*` and a `char*`. There is not a direct comparison function between the two so it will be necessary to convert from a `string` to a `wstring`. There are lots of examples of how to do that, such as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7159944/2642059 and you'll need to do something similar, for example:

```
wstring get_wstring(const string& s) {
    wstring buf;
    const char* cs = s.c_str();
    const size_t wn = mbsrtowcs(nullptr, &cs, 0, nullptr);

    if (wn == string::npos) {
        cout << "Error in mbsrtowcs(): " << errno << endl;
    } else {
        buf.resize(wn + 1);

        if(mbsrtowcs(&*buf.begin(), &cs, wn + 1, nullptr) == string::npos) {
            cout << "Error in mbsrtowcs(): " << errno << endl;
            buf.resize(0);
        }
    }

    return buf;
}
```

The return of `get_wstring(expected)` and `actual` will now both be `wchar`s and can thereby be compared in the using [`AreEqual(String^, String^, bool)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243448.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)