# Default type assumption by a template function

Tags: c++, templates

Example: Assuming `f` to be a template function, having two arguments:

`f (1, 2)` In this call, does the template function assume that its arguments are `int`, or `short`, or anything else?

EDIT 1:

The template function declaration:

`template <typename dataTypeA, typename dataTypeB> dataTypeB functionX (dataTypeA argA, dataTypeB argB)`

Comment: @Kerrek SB You can assume that the template function just prints out the two arguments.

Comment: A bit nitpicking: It is called "function template" because it is a template, not a function. Recalling this fact sometimes helps to understand some issues you might run into ("but I give it a function, why does the compiler complain" "no, you give it a template")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @David already said, as far as your question is concerned, there's no such thing as "making assumptions". The [literals](http://c.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html) simply have types, which are the types that a function template may use for type deduction. Remember that conversions considered as part of the template matching, though!

So, let's say you have this function template:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T x, T y);
```

Then if you call `foo(1, 2)`, this will be called with `T = int`.

If you say `foo(1u, 2u)`, the deduction is `T = unsigned int`.

If you say anything mixed like `foo(1u, 2)`, there is no preferred match and the compiler will report an error.

Since there is no `short` literal in C or C++, if you want to explicitly call the function `foo<short>`, you can either say so, or create temporary explicit`short` arguments:

```
foo<short int>(3, 4);
foo<short int>(3u, 4l);  // also OK because of conversion
foo(short(3), short(4)); // deduction
```

---

Update: In light of your edit, note that since you're only matching one argument per template parameter, you won't have any trouble with ambiguous matching.

Comment: The one that puzzled me was `foo(1u, 1l);` as no preferred match since `T = long` would work without any loss. (But makese sense since you *could* have `sizeof(long) == sizeof(unsigned)` on some other platform)

Comment: @Awoodland: I'm sure there's a perfect standardese explanation involving the matching rules and implicit conversion, but I'm not 100% sure on those, so hopefully someone will come and state that :-) @Anisha: One nitpick, the literal `L'a'` is of type `wchar_t`, *not* `short int`, and likewise for `L"hello"` arrays. That's a mistake on that site, beware. I just noticed it and thought that's important to point out for your situation.

Comment: Indeed, it was important to point out, thanks. Do point out if there is something else wrong too. :)

Comment: @Anisha: Well, the site is missing the sexy new C++11/C1x [Unicode string literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c0x) of which I'm a great fan, though they may not be of immediate use to you. Also C++11 has overloadable (postfix) literals, in theory.

Comment: Thanks, and please add that link to your OP, since people may miss reading the comments.

Comment: Also, `unsigned short int : L'ab'` is shown for unsigned short in that link, why are they referring 'a' 'b' there? why not, '1' '2'? And they don't have anything for `short`?

Comment: @Anisha: You know what, please ignore the first three rows of that table, that's all misleading and wrong. You can't have multi-character character literals, and "ASCII" is also wrong. I'd replace the link by a better one if I had one. In any event, there is no `short` literal. I guess it's a C legacy, in C every small integral was promoted to `int` (e.g. in C, 'a' is an int, not a char) at the slightest provocation. Presumably nobody felt the need to refit C++ with a short int literal. Double check your promotion rules, though, especially when doing arithmetic.

Comment: @Anisha: The [IBM documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/conref.htm) is much better, but it's also a lot harder to read. If you find a good summary of C++ literal constant syntax, do say.

Comment: Thanks for the effort :hattip: I have put the question here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/c-literal-for-short-and-unsigned-short-899372/ Lets see if they can answer something.

Answer (score 7):

The template does not *assume* anything. The literals are of type `int`, and that will be the type that the compiler deduces.

Comment: and why not of type `short`? `1` and `2` fit in shorts too. Is this compiler dependent?

Comment: @Anisha: No, the *literal* `1`, as written in your source code, has a type, and that type is `int`. If you write `1u` the type is `unsigned int`, and `1l` is `long int` etc. I don't think there's a `short` literal.

Comment: @Kerrek that was helpful, thanks. I didn't know that it is permissible to write `1u` too. So, the only way to pass a `short` value will be like `short h = 10`? See if you can write that as a separate somewhat detailed answer, I'll select it.

Comment: You can create a short in place. OK, let me spin up my crystal ball and guess what you might be doing.

Comment: @Anisha: you can also force the type, either by providing the type argument to the template `f<short>(5)` (assuming `template <typename T> void f( T );`) or by casting the argument: `f( (short)5 )`

Comment: It's odd that there's no `short` literal since there is a `char` literal and that makes `short` the only integer type with no literal.

Comment: @Kerrek and what was this pun for? `OK, let me spin up my crystal ball and guess what you might be doing.`

Comment: @David - you could also use `f(short(5))` syntax.

Comment: David, your comment was helpful, thanks. What is the literal for a `char`?

Comment: `char` literal is just `'a'` or similar.

Comment: @Anisha: the pun is because I have no idea what your actual code or problem is, so I can merely make some general statement about function templates and argument deductions and hope that it applies to your situation. The crystal ball is often cloudy, but sometimes it works :-)

Comment: @Kerrek I didn't present the code, since I thought that it is a "conceptual" matter. What the function does from inside doesn't matter, IMO.

Comment: @Anisha: No no, you misunderstand. The function definition is indeed irrelevant. But the function template declaration would have been immensely useful. From your question, your function template could have been `template <typename T> char foo(T, int)`, `template <typename T> bool foo(T, T)`, or even `template <typename T> T foo(int, int)`, and there's no way of knowing, and they all have different answers. I guessed the most likely one, but you could just have made this clear in the question.

Comment: @Kerrek alright, I misunderstood you, but you didn't state it clearly too that you wanted the "declaration" only. I'll edit the OP. :)

Comment: @Anisha: Welcome to SO :-) When people say "post the code", they mean, "post *some* representative, minimal code that makes the question clear", they don't want you to post your entire source file :-)