# Unicode string literals

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, string-literals, unicode-literals

C++11 introduces a new set of string literal prefixes (and even allows user-defined suffixes). On top of this, you can directly use Unicode escape sequences to code a certain symbol without having to worry about encoding.

```
const char16_t* s16 = u"\u00DA";
const char32_t* s32 = U"\u00DA";
```

But can I use the unicode escape sequences in `wchar_t` string literals as well? It would seem to be a defect if this wasn't possible.

```
const wchar_t* sw = L"\u00DA";
```

The integer value of `sw[0]` would of course depend on what `wchar_t` is on a particular platform, but to all other effects, this should be portable, no?

Comment: I believe the value of `sw[0]` depends on what `wchar_t` is on a particular platform only to the extent of what the size of `wchar_t` is. I.e. `\u00DA` should always result in some Unicode encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32) of U+00DA, even when that's not the platform's normal encoding for that type.

Comment: Actually the above is incorrect. The implementation is supposed to treat universal character names as it would the literal character. So if the implementation translates characters in a string literal to the execution character set then it should do so with UCNs as well. You're only guaranteed the UTF encoding if the UCN is inside a unicode literal (e.g., u8"\u00DA").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would work, but it may not have the desired semantics. `\u00DA` will expand into as many target characters as necessary for UTF8/16/32 encoding, depending on the size of `wchar_t`, but bear in mind that wide strings do not have any documented, guaranteed encoding semantics -- they're simply "the system's encoding", with no attempt made to say what that is, or require the user to *know* what that is.

So it's best not to mix and match. Use either one, but not both, of the two:

1. system-specific: `char*`/`""`, `wchar_t*`/`L""`, `\x`-literals, `mbstowcs`/`wcstombs`
2. Unicode: `char*`/`u8""`, `char16_t*`/`u""`, `char32_t*`/`U""`, `\u`/`\U` literals.

(Here are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c0x) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562609/what-does-cuchar-provide-and-where-is-it-documented) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) of mine on the subject.)

Comment: For the full details as to the background of this question, [this libc++ test](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/test/localization/locale.categories/category.ctype/locale.ctype.byname/is_1.pass.cpp) is failing on Windows at the `\x00DA` line. I wonder if I could replace this with `\u00DA` and have it work for all `wchar_t`'s that are large enough (ie 16 or 32-bit)

Comment: /u is for utf16, /U is for utf32, what is for utf8? (and I don't mean the string prefix, that's u8, I mean the hex prefix inside the string)

Comment: You mean \, not /? Those are two different things. Also please note that I never said `\u` is for UTF-16. The escaped value is always an abstract codepoint (= number); it's just that `\U` takes a 32-bit number and `\u` takes a 16-bit number. I'm not really sure what a correct version of your question might be, perhaps something like an 8-bit-constrained codepoint reference, i.e. codepoints in the range [0, 256)? I guess that could exist, but it'd have extremely limited value, since most of those codepoints are readily available via ASCII and don't need escaping.