# UTF-8-compliant IOstreams

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, iostream, filestreams

Does GCC's standard library or Boost or any other library implement iostream-compliant versions of `ifstream` or `ofstream` that supports conversion between UTF-8-encoded (file-) streams and a `std::vector<wchar_t>` or `std::wstring`?

Comment: Have you tried `std::wifstream` ? It may just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't quite work. UTF-8 is a specific encoding, while `wchar_t` is a data type. Moreover, `wchar_t` is intended by the standard to represent *the system's character set*, but this is entirely left to platform, and the standard makes no requirements.

Therefore, the correct thing to ask for is first of all conversion between *the system's narrow, multibyte encoding* and the fixed-length encoding of the system's encoding into a wide string. This functionality is provided by `std::mbstowcs` and `std::wcstombs`. There may also be a locale facet somewhere that wraps this, but that's a bit of a niche area of the library.

If you want to convert between the opaque "system's encoding" prescribed by the standard and a definite encoding prescribed by your serialized data source/sink, you need an extra library. I'd recommend Posix's `iconv()`, which is widely available. (The Windows API has a different approach and offers special functions for conversion.)

C++11 alleviates the issue slightly by adding an explicit family of UTF-encoded string types and literals, and presumably also transcoding facilities among those (though I've never seen them implemented by anyone).

Here's my standard response of past posts on the subject: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c0x), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562609/what-does-cuchar-provide-and-where-is-it-documented). C++11 will be a joy once its fully available :-)

Comment: C++11's explicit UTF8/UTF16/UCS2/UCS4 conversions have been implemented in clang++/libc++ and in Visual Studio 2010 for quite a while now. The following runs on both: https://ideone.com/hywz6

Comment: @Cubbi: Thanks! What about `<cuchar>` (see my Q3)?

Comment: Those I haven't had a chance to try out. [dunkumware says](http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=uchar.html#mbrtoc16) it has them.

Answer (score 4):

The C++11 solution is to wrap the UTF-8 stream in an appropriate `wbuffer_convert`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream utf8file("test.txt"); // if the file holds UTF-8 data
    std::wbuffer_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> conv(utf8file.rdbuf());
    std::wistream ucsbuf(&conv);
    std::wstring line;
    getline(ucsbuf, line); // then line holds UCS2 or UCS4, depending on the OS
}
```

This works with Visual Studio 2010 and with clang++/libc++, but, unfortunately, not with GCC.

Until this becomes widespread, third-party libraries are indeed the best solution.

Comment: Does this convert UTF8 to WCHAR, or only to other UTFs? It'd be very nice if UTF<->WCHAR conversion were part of the standard!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Indeed, locale-independent codecvt's produce only UTF-16, UCS2, or UTF-32. Not the wctombs-compatible opaque wide character encoding.