# Working with unicode strings as std::vector<unsigned short>

Tags: c++

A library stores unicode strings as.

```
std::vector<unsigned short> ustring;
```

How do I do these conversions in a portable way?

```
convert ustring to std::wstring;
convert ustring to std::string;
convert ustring to std::vector<unsigned char>;
convert std::vector<unsigned char> to ustring;
```

EDIT
The strings are probably UTF-16 not UTF-8

Comment: Are you sure they're not UTF-16 strings? Storing UTF-8 as `unsigned short` vectors wastes 50% space on typical platforms.

Comment: Are you sure they're not just *code points*?

Comment: What is the name of the library? ustring to wstring should be no problem as wstring are wchar_ts which should also by short sized. If you wish to preserve the contents you will probably need to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 when going for strings or chars. If you need to go from char to ustring you need to convert the characters. Take a look at the libaray ICU.

Comment: @RedX : `wchar_t` is only `short`-sized on Windows; on other platforms, it is typically `int`-sized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/), [icu](http://icu-project.org/), [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/), and others can do this.  AFAIK, C++ does not have a portable way to convert between UTF8/16/32.  Keep in mind that `std::wstring` is UTF16 on some systems, and UTF32 on others.

Comment: Also [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/), which is header-only and quite simple to use.

Comment: ICU (if you're using the rest of it already) also has UTF conversion macros in utf.h and similar.

Answer (score 0):

- Conversion to wide strings: Use `iconv()`.
- Conversion between UTF8/16/32: Now a built-in feature of C++11, but not widely supported yet. Alternatively, use `iconv()`. Also use `std::u16string` and `std::u32string` as the data type of choice (and `std::string` for UTF8).
- Conversion from wide string to system's multibyte narrow string: use `wcstombs()`/`mbstowcs()`.

Here's my standard response of past posts on the subject: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c0x), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562609/what-does-cuchar-provide-and-where-is-it-documented).