# Is there no std::to_u16string or std::to_u32string?

Tags: c++, c++11, tostring

I was happy for the standard library to get a `to_string` function, but now I'm in WTF mode. First of all why isn't this templated, second of all if it is not a template on return value then why in the world they don't have `to_u16string()` and `to_u32string()` functions.

I know that there is boost lexical cast, but I'm curious to know if there is a standard way to get what I want without manually writing these functions?

EDIT: to make matters worse boost 1.46 also dislikes u16string :(

```
boost::lexical_cast<u16string>(22.44);
```

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl
>
> > '   what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232710/c0x-convert-between-string-u16string-u32string

Comment: There's no `to_string` in the STL.

Comment: While I fully agree with Tomalak on the whining, I'm not sure what is not constructive about this question compared to others. There have been plenty of "why does language X do thing Y?" questions. Most of them are not closed. Yes, this question is *very* badly stated. But at it's core, it's really just asking about `std::to_string` and its ilk.

Comment: also it asks why boost also fails to do the conversion, but I think it was answered... C++ cant do it so I guess boost cant do it easily...

Comment: also what if cpp gets unicode support. then I guess template writers gonna be pretty pissed that there is no std::tostring<*string_type*>  I guess they can always add to_basic_string<*string_type*> though... it just looks like terrible design decision to me...

Comment: Ranting aside, this is a perfectly valid question, voting to reopen.

Comment: You can easily solve this issue btw with two lines of code:
`wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<char32_t>, char32_t> utf32conv;
 auto to_u32string = [&] (const auto& value) -> u32string {return utf32conv.from_bytes(to_string(value));};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relax and take a deep breath before you collapse.

It all makes perfect sense. `to_string` and `to_wstring` use `sprintf`/`wsprintf`. There is nothing in the language that crosses the bridge between agnostic narrow/wide encoding and the UTF encodings, so there simply does not exist a standard library facility to *produce* UTF-encoded strings. The new UTF-facilities allow you to *store* UTF-encoded strings and transcode among them, but there is no way to encode a system-specific encoding to a UTF-encoding without the help of an extra library.

How would those "20 lines of code" look like that you propose? Include floating point numbers, please.

(Here are my standard question links on the subject: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c0x), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562609/what-does-cuchar-provide-and-where-is-it-documented))

Comment: So u are telling me that there is no way to convert numbers(float or int) in standard cpp to unicode strings?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Correct. You will need an external library, such as `iconv()`. Then again, you're the one who boasted that you *could* do it in 20 lines, so I'm still curious how you propose to do that.

Comment: ok, what about doing simple to_wstring and then casting the that to u16string... I mean I really dont get why converting NUMBER to unicode string is not possible without external lib.

Comment: Read my linked posts. Wide strings have nothing to do with Unicode. They simply don't. And again, if you think you can do it, please do, and post! (I admit that it ought to be easy for integers.)

Comment: so u are saying that  . , and - are hard parts ?

Comment: @Kerrek SB Not all that easy if one wishes to convert between non-ASCII Unicode numerals (say, [U+0660](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/660/index.htm) - [U+0669](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/669/index.htm)) and integers... perhaps I want too much, but Java can convert those characters to correct digits individually.

Comment: @NoSense - The standard doesn't say how a  `wstring` is encoded. It could just as well be equivalent to a `u32string`. Or something else.

Comment: @Cubbi: You're entirely correct, it's not trivial even for integers - it's not terribly *hard* for integers, though, if you permit `to_string()` as an intermediate step.

Comment: OK, I'm totally lost... what prohibits one to use u'-', u'.', u'0',u'1', u'2'... u'9' to do to_u16string

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: yes, it should be straight-forward for integers. I had thought for a moment that `sprintf` is locale-aware, but it isn't in the default mode (`%i` and `%d`). To get floating point numbers, you'd essentially have to copy the `sprintf` code and make all the necessary adjustments. A `uNNsprintf` would be the most obvious first step, so this should be requested of the C library first of all.