# How to check japanese or english character

Tags: c++, string

My code here:

```
std::string st = "名前hlong"; 
for (int i = 0; i < st.lenght(); i++) 
{ 
   char *ch = st[i];
   if ((int)ch <= 255))
   { 
     //Character is latin. 
   } 
   else 
   { 
     //Character is japanese 
   } 
}
```

I want to count the number of Japanese and English characters.
But it's not working.
Please help me resolve this issue.
Thanks all.

Comment: Do you want to classify the characters, i.e. get *separate* counts for Japanese and Latin characters?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have worked? What haven't worked? What does your code look like? You do know about [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and its encodings?

Comment: Yes, please help me classify the characters.

Comment: std::string st = "名前hlong";
//I want to count the number is japanese in this string.

Comment: Does this help:- [std::wstring VS std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring) and [Handling UTF-8 in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513249/handling-utf-8-in-c)

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=japanese+unicode&) you will find tables of Japanese unicode. I guess that's all you need to distinguish UTF8 representations of Japanese characters from "English" ones.

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters & http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2922e8c9-426a-41bd-a4e2-1ca948c6c0ec/how-to-get-a-unicode-value-of-a-character?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you shouldn't use std::string because std::string is byte-oriented and a Japanese  character can't be represented as a single byte. You should use std::wstring (or in C++11 `std::u16string` and `std::u32string` for UTF-16 and UTF-32).

Consider the following C++11 code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
        wstring s = L"Привет , 名前 hlong";
        for(wchar_t c: s)
               cout << "Char code = 0x" << hex << int(c) << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

it's compiled with GCC-4.7 as follows `g++ -finput-charset=utf-8 -std=c++11 test_wstring.cc -o test_wstring` and produces the following output (0x20 stands for space character):

```
Char code = 0x41f
Char code = 0x440
Char code = 0x438
Char code = 0x432
Char code = 0x435
Char code = 0x442
Char code = 0x20
Char code = 0x2c
Char code = 0x20
Char code = 0x540d
Char code = 0x524d
Char code = 0x20
Char code = 0x68
Char code = 0x6c
Char code = 0x6f
Char code = 0x6e
Char code = 0x67
```

As you may see standard ASCII characters are in range 0-0xFF, Cyrillic characters are 0x400+ and Japanese ones are 0x524d and 0x540d. You should check the Unicode tables mentioned in the comments and see what ranges you're interested in. Also you may consider std::codecvt facilities & Co to convert between byte and character-oriented encodings , see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt

Comment: Japanese characters may be representable as multi-byte characters, and it's possible to check for those in a `std::string`, just not by comparing the values to 255. Other than that, I think your answer is more useful than mine, I'll delete mine.

Comment: Well, if we talk about UTF-8 string then, yes, it's possible to check if a given byte belongs to a sequence of bytes representing a single character. Likely, a single Japanese character is represented as 3 bytes in a UTF-8 byte stream. The first byte of the 3 in both 名 and 前 is equal to 0xE5. But it would be a rather boring and complex check because it requires proper decoding of all byte sequences preceding a given byte. So usually it's better to convert a UTF sequence to std::wstring and then use common character access methods of std::basic_string: `[]`, `at()` etc

Comment: Yes, I completely agree that you shouldn't use `std::string`. I only commented because your answer seems to imply that you *cannot* use `std::string`. But perhaps I'm reading too much into it.