# clang: converting const char16_t* (UTF-16) to wstring (UCS-4)

Tags: c++, macos, unicode, c++11, clang

I'm trying to convert UTF-16 encoded strings to UCS-4

If I understand correctly, C++11 provides this conversion through codecvt_utf16.

My code is something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <memory>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    u16string s;

    s.push_back('h');
    s.push_back('e');
    s.push_back('l');
    s.push_back('l');
    s.push_back('o');

    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conv;
    wstring ws = conv.from_bytes(reinterpret_cast<const char*> (s.c_str()));

    wcout << ws << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: the explicit push_backs to get around the fact that my version of clang (Xcode 4.2) doesn't have unicode string literals.

When the code is run, I get terminate exception. Am I doing something illegal here? I was thinking it should work because the const char* that I passed to wstring_convert is UTF-16 encoded, right? I have also considered endianness being the issue, but I have checked that it's not the case.

Comment: In principle, there should be some convenience functions in `<cuchar>` somewhere, but I've [had trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562609/what-does-cuchar-provide-and-where-is-it-documented) finding out how those work.

Comment: @Kerrek SB `<cuchar>` is locale-dependent, the question is about Unicode to Unicode conversion, no locales involved.

Comment: @Cubbi: Hm, pretty sure that `<cuchar>` has nothing to do with locales, but I might be wrong...

Comment: @Kerreck SB: On second thought, you're right, one could c16rtomb followed by mbrtoc32, abstracting the locale-specific multibyte encoding away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two errors:

1) `from_bytes()` overload that takes the single `const char*` expects a null-terminated byte string, but your very second byte is '\0'.

2) your system is likely little-endian, so you need to convert from UTF-16LE to UCS-4:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <memory>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    u16string s;

    s.push_back('h');
    s.push_back('e');
    s.push_back('l');
    s.push_back('l');
    s.push_back('o');

    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, little_endian>,
                     wchar_t> conv;
    wstring ws = conv.from_bytes(
                     reinterpret_cast<const char*> (&s[0]),
                     reinterpret_cast<const char*> (&s[0] + s.size()));

    wcout << ws << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Tested with Visual Studio 2010 SP1 on Windows and CLang++/libc++-svn on Linux.

Comment: PS, this should be using char32_t to guarantee UCS4, of course. The wchar_t version produces UTF-16 where wchar_t is 16 bit.

Comment: This is a very awesome answer, and I salute you for knowing all this really! I'd upvote the answer 3 more times if I could. May I also ask more questions if allowed:
1. Can you tell me the concept of MaxCode which you set to 0x10ffff? Cause I notice that it's actually needed..
2. Good point about '\0' being the terminator of const char*. Makes me quickly wonder, what would be the corresponding terminator for char16_t* ?
Thanks again.

Comment: @ryaner `Maxcode` is just the limit on the acceptable character values, it's only needed here because endianness/BOM handling indicator happens to be the third template parameter, which I think is a small design flaw. The terminating character for a null-terminated array of `chat16_t` is `char16_t()` aka `u'\0'`

Comment: it does not work for example in case of       std::u16string s = u"\U00010330";

Comment: @elgcom works for me http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8b1bc6d6b6b7c9b

Comment: @Cubbi on clang yes, but on VC++ failed.  http://rextester.com/CWIGH25202

Comment: @elgcom On Windows, wstring is not UCS-4, it's UCS-2 (or, in some APIs, UTF-16), and your char can't be represented in UCS-2.

Comment: @Cubbi hmm, not really clear to me. Basiclly wstring can store such unicode string. (e.g. wstring = L"\U00010330") and alternatively I can convert such u16string at first to utf8 std::string then to std::wstring without problem.  Why codecvt_utf16 can not be smart enough?

Comment: @elgcom it's as smart as it can be. All of C++ (and C) standard library assumes wchar_t is 32 bit (informally speaking). Because it's permanently broken in Windows is pretty much the reason we got char32_t in C11 and C++11.