# how does one convert std::u16string -> std::wstring using <codecvt>?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, type-conversion

I found a bunch of questions on a similar topic, but nothing regarding wide to wide conversion with `<codecvt>`, which is supposed to be the correct choice in the modern code.

The `std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>` seems to be a logical choice to perform the conversion.

However `std::wstring_convert` seem to expect `std::string` at one end. The methods `from_bytes` and `to_bytes` emphasize this purpose.

I mean, the best solution so far is something like `std::copy`, which might work for my specific case, but seems kinda low tech and probably not too correct either.

I have a string feeling that I am missing something rather obvious.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::wstring_convert` and `std::codecvt...` classes are deprecated in C++17 onward. There is no longer a standard way to convert between the various string classes.

If your compiler still supports the classes, you can certainly use them.  However, you cannot convert *directly* from `std::u16string` to `std::wstring` (and vice versa) with them.  You will have to convert to an intermediate UTF-8 `std::string` first, and then convert that afterwards, eg:

```cpp
std::u16string utf16 = ...;

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> utf16conv;
std::string utf8 = utf16conv.to_bytes(utf16);

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> wconv;
std::wstring wstr = wconv.from_bytes(utf8);
```

Just know that this approach *will* break when the classes are eventually dropped from the standard library.

Using `std::copy()` (or simply the various `std::wstring` data construct/assign methods) will work only on Windows, where `wchar_t` and `char16_t` are both 16-bit in size representing UTF-16:

```cpp
std::u16string utf16 = ...;
std::wstring wstr;

#ifdef _WIN32
wstr.reserve(utf16.size());
std::copy(utf16.begin(), utf16.end(), std::back_inserter(wstr));
/*
or: wstr = std::wstring(utf16.begin(), utf16.end());
or: wstr.assign(utf16.begin(), utf16.end());
or: wstr = std::wstring(reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(utf16.c_str()), utf16.size());
or: wstr.assign(reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(utf16.c_str()), utf16.size());
*/
#else
// do something else ...
#endif
```

But, on other platforms, where `wchar_t` is 32-bit in size representing UTF-32, you will need to actually convert the data, using the code shown above, or a platform-specific API or 3rd party Unicode library that can do the data conversion, such as `libiconv`, `ICU`. etc.

Answer (score 0):

> you cannot convert directly from std::u16string to std::wstring (and vice versa) with them. You will have to convert to an intermediate UTF-8 std::string first, and then convert that afterwards

This doesn't appear to be the case as
[clang: converting const char16_t* (UTF-16) to wstring (UCS-4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540090/clang-converting-const-char16-t-utf-16-to-wstring-ucs-4)
shows:

```
u16string s = u"hello";
wstring_convert<codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, little_endian>,
                 wchar_t> conv;
wstring ws = conv.from_bytes(
                 reinterpret_cast<const char*> (&s[0]),
                 reinterpret_cast<const char*> (&s[0] + s.size()));
```