# Convert wchar_t* to UTF-16 string

Tags: c++, c, unicode, utf-16, wchar-t

I need a code in C++ to convert a string given in `wchar_t*` to a UTF-16 string. It must work both on Windows and Linux. I've looked through a lot of web-pages during the search, but the subject still is not clear to me.

As I understand I need to:

1. Call `setlocale` with LC_TYPE and UTF-16 encoding.
2. Use `wcstombs` to convert `wchar_t` to UTF-16 string.
3. Call `setlocale` to restore previous locale.

Do you know the way I can convert `wchar_t*` to UTF-16 in a portable way (Windows and Linux)?

Comment: Maybe my encoding-related questions [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability), [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c0x), [#3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562609/what-does-cuchar-provide-and-where-is-it-documented) are of some use.

Comment: Which code set is the `wchar_t` string in?  What type do you expect to use to represent the character type in the UTF-16 string?  Is this simply a transform between UTF-32 (in the `wchar_t`) and UTF-16 in `uint16_t`?  Or are you dealing with codeset conversion too?  Portability is a noble goal; it is not always achievable, sadly.  Do investigate [ICU](http://icu-project.org/).

Answer (score 8):

There is no single cross-platform method for doing this in C++03 (not without a library). This is in part because `wchar_t` is itself not the same thing across platforms. Under Windows, `wchar_t` is a 16-bit value, while on other platforms it is often a 32-bit value. So you would need two different codepaths to do it.

Answer (score 5):

C++11's `std::codecvt_utf16` should work, I think.

> std::codecvt_utf16 is a std::codecvt facet which encapsulates conversion between a UTF-16 encoded byte string and UCS2 or UCS4 character string (depending on the type of Elem).

See this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16

Comment: All well and good, except G++ (or, more precisely, libstdc++) doesn't provide the `<codecvt>` header yet, so `std::codecvt_utf16` is not available.

Comment: C++11 also introduces `char16_t` and `char32_t` types (and associated `std::basic_string` typedefs) to get away from `wchar_t` platform issues. For instance, use `std::u16string` wherever you need a UTF-16 encoded string.

Answer (score 3):

You can assume that wchar_t is utf-32 in the non-Windows world. It is true on Linux and Mac OS X and most *nix systems (there are very few exceptions to that, and on systems you will probably never touch :-)

And wchar_t is utf-16 on Windows. So on Windows the conversion function can just do a memcpy :-)

On everything else, the conversion is algorithmic, and pretty simple. So there is no need of fancy support from 3rd party libraries.

Here is the basic algorithm: http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-3

And you can probably find find a dozen different implementations if you don't want to write your own :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `wchar_t` being rather underspecified. You could use GNU libiconv to do what you want. It accepts special encoding name `"wchar_t"` as both source and target encoding. That way it will be portable to both Windows and Linux and elsewhere where you can provide libiconv.

Answer (score -1):

The g++ compiler appears to support wcstombs?

Comment: Are you asking a question or stating a fact?