# How to get the UNICODE code from each character of a UTF-8 string?

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, encoding, utf-8

With C++11, how can I, from an UTF-8 encoded `std::string`, get the Unicode value of each character of the text into an `uint32_t`?

Something like:

```
void f(const std::string &utf8_str)
{
    for(???) {
       uint32_t code = ???;

       /* Do my stuff with the code... */
    }
}
```

Does assuming the host system locale is UTF-8 helps? What standard library tools C++11 offers for the task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply convert the string into a UTF-32 encoded one, using the provided conversion facet and [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) from `<locale>`:

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

void foo(std::string const & utf8str)
{
     std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv;
     std::u32string utf32str = conv.from_bytes(utf8str);

     for (char32_t u : utf32str)  { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to get, instead of UTF-8, the codecvt for the system native encoding?

Comment: @lvella: You can convert the system's narrow encoding to UTF32 with [`mbrtoc32`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbrtoc32). The table at the bottom of the linked page shows all the available combinations. ([I'm not sure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562609/what-does-cuchar-provide-and-where-is-it-documented) if `<cuchar>` is widely implemented yet, though.)

Comment: @lvella the system's native encoding instead of UTF-8? If you mean something like GB18030 (another 8-bit Unicode format), then you can use codecvt_byname or pull it out of the locale with use_facet. [This example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/wstring_convert) shows how to build a wstring_convert with it.

Comment: ...and you probably need to call `std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` or something appropriate for the stream in question to obtain the actual system locale...

Comment: That `mbrtoc32` is a very weird thing... it documents negative return values, but returns a `size_t`, that is unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<utf8.h>` from  http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/ you could code:

```
 static inline void fix_utf8_string(std::string& str)
 {
   std::string temp;
   utf8::replace_invalid(str.begin(), str.end(), back_inserter(temp));
   str = temp;
 }

 static inline bool valid_utf8_cstr(const char*s)
 {
   if (!s) return false;
   const char* e = s+strlen(s);
   return utf8::is_valid(s,e);
 }

 static inline size_t
 utf8_length(const char*s)
 {
   if (!s) return 0;
   const char* e = s+strlen(s);
   return utf8::distance(s,e);
 }


 // apply a function to every code point, exiting if that function
 // gives true and return the number of visited code points
 static inline size_t
 utf8_foreach_if(const char*s, 
                 std::function<bool(uint32_t,size_t)>f)
 {
   if (!s) return 0;
   size_t ix=0;
   const char*pc = s;
   while(*pc)
     {
       const char*epc
         = (pc[1]==0)?(pc+1):(pc[2]==0)
              ?(pc+2):(pc[3]==0)?(pc+3):(pc+4);
       uint32_t c = utf8::next(pc,epc);
       if (f(c,ix)) break;
       ix++;
     };
   return ix;
 }

 static inline size_t
 utf8_foreach_if(const std::string& s, 
                 std::function<bool(uint32_t,size_t)>f)
 {
   if (s.empty()) return 0;
   size_t ix=0;
   const char*pc = s.c_str();
   const char*epc = pc + s.size();
   while(*pc)
     {
       uint32_t c = utf8::next(pc,epc);
       if (f(c,ix)) break;
       ix++;
     };
   return ix;
 }
```

This is extracted from some code licensed under GPLv3 that I will release in a few weeks or months.