# UTF-8 conversion for characters

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode

I currently have a `std::string` and it contains this

```
"\xa9 2006 FooWorld"
```

Basically it contains the symbol © . This string is being passed to a method to an external API that takes in UTF-8. How could I make this string UTF-8 compatible ? Any suggestions. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603400/unicode-to-utf-8-in-c) I could use `std::wstring_convert` but I am not sure how to apply it in my case. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: For that one character it's probably not worth anything complicated. Just hardcode the utf-8 equivalent. http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: The thing is it could be multiple characters

Comment: You should probably have that in the question. :) Personally, I'd use this: http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: `std::string` stores bytes, not characters. So if you do not know the original encoding, there's no way guaranteed to work. If you know the original encoding is utf8, then you do not need anything extra, because, again, `std::string` stores the encoding bytes.

Comment: maybe you want to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple: use a UTF-8 string literal:

```
u8"\u00A9 2006 FooWorld"
```

That will result in a `const char[]` that is a properly encoded UTF-8 string.

Comment: for instance if I have ``std::basic_string str = "\xa9 2006 FooWorld"`` How do I append u8 to it ?

Comment: @MistyD: You change the code to read: `std::string str = u8"\u00A9 2006 FooWorld"`. If you're not allowed to change the literal itself, then this is a duplicate as previously outlined.

Comment: When using any of the Unicode-aware literal prefixes, you can use the actual Unicode character instead of using its codepoint/codeunits manually, eg: `u8"© 2006 FooWorld"`. Let the compiler do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 and later, the best way to get a UTF-8 encoded string literal is to use the `u8` prefix:

```
std:string str = u8"\u00A9 2006 FooWorld";
```

or:

```
std:string str = u8"© 2006 FooWorld";
```

However, you *can* use `std::wstring_convert`, too (especially if your input data is not a string literal):

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

std::wstring wstr = L"© 2006 FooWorld"; // or whatever...

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;

std::string str = convert.to_bytes(wstr);
```