# Reading/writing/printing UTF-8 in C++11

Tags: utf-8, c++11, wchar-t, utf-32, codecvt

I have been exploring C++11's new Unicode functionality, and while [other C++11 encoding questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c11) have been very helpful, I have a question about the following code snippet from  [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16). The code writes and then immediately reads a text file saved with UTF-8 encoding.

```
// Write
std::ofstream("text.txt") << u8"z\u6c34\U0001d10b";

// Read
std::wifstream file1("text.txt");
file1.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF8"));
std::cout << "Normal read from file (using default UTF-8/UTF-32 codecvt)\n";
for(wchar_t c; file1 >> c; ) // ?
   std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << c << '\n';
```

My question is quite simply, why is a `wchar_t` needed in the `for` loop? A `u8` string literal can be declared using a simple `char *` and the bit layout of the UTF-8 encoding should tell the system the character's width. It appears there is some automatic conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-32 (hence the `wchar_t`), but if this is the case, why is the conversion necessary?

Comment: It depends on a lot of things. Notable, correct UTF8 behaviour is extremely hard if not impossible using Windows in a console application (requiring _at least_ a good number of non-standard API calls IIRC)

Comment: `wchar_t` is used because `wifstream` is used, and `wifstream` performs that "some automatic conversion" you mention. My point was to show the difference between that automatic conversion (as implemented for one particular platform) and the explicit, portable, locale-independent, Unicode conversion provided by `codecvt_utf8_utf16`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `wchar_t` because you're reading the file using `wifstream`; if you were reading using `ifstream` you'd use `char`, and similarly for `char16_t` and `char32_t`.

*Assuming* (as the example does) that `wchar_t` is 32-bit, and that the native character set that it represents is UTF-32 (UCS-4), then this is the simplest way to read a file as UTF-32; it is presented as such in the example for contrast to reading a file as UTF-16.  A more portable method would be to use `basic_ifstream<char32_t>` and `std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>` explicitly, as this is guaranteed to convert from a UTF-8 input stream to UTF-32 elements.

Comment: +1, I wrote that example and contrast was what I was going for.

Comment: Ah I see! So is it therefore better practice to always explicitly convert UTF-8 to a wider `wchar_t` or is it still acceptable to just extract the raw UTF-8 bytes into a native `char` array using an `ifstream`? I'm not sure whether to infer from @Cubbi's example that the latter is bad practice, or whether it is just outside the scope of the example.

Comment: @PLPiper yes you can always read whatever multibyte encoding the file has into a char array, without engaging any of the conversions. There isn't a lot that can be done with such array within standard C++ (other than converting to wide first), but plenty of libraries take utf8 inputs.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the cppreference code snippet you used is to show how to read a UTF-8 file into a UTF-16 string that's why they write the file using an ofstream but read it using a wifstream (hence the wchar_t).