# Converting UTF-16 to UTF-8 using libiconv

Tags: c, character-encoding, libiconv

I'm trying to convert an UTF-16 string into utf-8 and hit a little wall. The output string contains the caracters but with blank spaces!? The input is `hi\0` and If I look at the output, it says `h\0i\0` instead of `hi\0`.

Do you see the problem here? Many thanks!

```
size_t len16 = 3 * sizeof(wchar_t);
size_t len8 = 7;
wchar_t utf16[3] = { 0x0068, 0x0069, 0x0000 }, *_utf16 = utf16;
char utf8[7], *_utf8 = utf8;

iconv_t utf16_to_utf8 = iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE");
size_t result = iconv(utf16_to_utf8, (char **)&_utf16, &len16, &_utf8, &len8);

printf("%d - %s\n", (int)result, utf8);

iconv_close(utf16_to_utf8);
```

Comment: I'd say that UTF-16 expects 2-byte code units (i.e. `uint16_t` or `char16_t`), and your `wchar_t` has a different size. [Nitpicker's Note: `iconv` is a Posix function, and Posix mandates `CHAR_BIT == 8`.]

Comment: @KerrekSB it seems to be the problem! Thanks, I'd be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input data for `iconv` is always an opaque byte stream. When reading UTF-16, `iconv` expects the input data to consist of two-byte code units. Therefore, if you want to provide hard-coded input data, you need to use a two-byte wide integral type.

In C++11 and C11 this should be `char16_t`, but you can also use `uint16_t`:

```
uint16_t data[] = { 0x68, 0x69, 0 };

char const * p = (char const *)data;
```

To be pedantic, there's nothing in general that says that `uint16_t` has two bytes. However, `iconv` is a Posix library, and Posix mandates that `CHAR_BIT == 8`, so it is true on Posix.

(Also note that the way you spell a literal value has *nothing* to do with the width of the type which you initialize with that value, so there's no difference between `0x68`, `0x0068`, or `0x00068`. What's much more interesting are the new Unicode character literals `\u` and `\U`, but that's a whole [different story](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6796157/596781).)