# What is the difference of the U prefix for a character literal vs. a string literal?

Tags: c++, unicode, string-literals

In *The C++ Programming Language C++ 4th edition*, section 6.2.6, it says:

> Combinations of R, L, and u prefixes are allowed, for example, `uR"\*\*(foo\\(bar))\*\*"`. Note the dramatic difference in the meaning of a U prefix for a character (unsigned) and for a string UTF-32 encoding (§7.3.2.2).

I don't quite understand what the author is trying to say here.  What is the "dramatic difference" indeed?  Why is the word "(unsigned)" used here?

Per my understanding, a U-prefixed character literal contains the ISO-10646 code point value of the quoted character, which is basically of the same idea as the U prefix of a string literal, and has nothing to do with the concept of "unsigned".

Comment: I don't understand either. `U"hello"` is a `char32_t const[6]` and `U'h'` is a `char32_t`. There's no dramatic difference to me.

Comment: @Simple Maybe the book is wrong? Or it is a matter of how you look at it whether you consider the differnce as dramatic or not?

Comment: All I can think is that a `U` *suffix* on an integer literal makes it unsigned? `char i = -159U; std::cout << i;` // prints "a"`

Comment: It's an error in the book.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned` is a C++ keyword and means that the integer type that (in most cases) follows in a declaration has only positive values.

For reference look here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Now for char and char[] you have:

```
char16_t c = u'\u00F6';
char32_t d = U'\U0010FFFF';
char16_t C[] = u"Hell\u00F6";
char32_t D[] = U"Hell\U000000F6\U0010FFFF";
```

For further reference to string literals:
[Unicode encoding for string literals in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c11)

So indeed there is some difference between `u` and `U` and `unsigned` but I wouldn't consider it dramatic.

Comment: I may have made myself unclear with the original phrasing of the question.  I have modified the question.  I know what "unsigned" is as a C++ keyword.  Sorry for the confusion.