# Strlen function giving wrong length when there are non-english characters in string

Tags: c, encoding, string-length, strlen, non-english

I have a program that accepts non-english characters also as an input field. Because we use `strlen`, it has failed to give expected length while calculating the length of the string when there is a non-english character. For input `nova`, output is `4` whereas for input `ñova`, the output is `5` whereas the output should be `4`.

1. `strlen("nova")` = `4`
2. `strlen("ñova")` = `5`

In the 2nd case, I would expect the output as `4` instead.

Comment: Hi. So what is your question? This is a question and answer forum. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298059/how-to-count-characters-in-a-unicode-string-in-c answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936646/getting-the-string-length-on-utf-8-in-c ? In what encoding is the `"ñova"` string? What operating system and localization settings do you use? `as an input field` What is an "input field", or what frameworks do you use to create an "input field", or what exactly is responsible for getting the characters from the user?

Comment: Going beyond 7 bit ASCII in C was always cumbersome - the language wasn't originally designed for such. You could try to use `wchar.h` and then `wcslen(L"ñova")`.

Comment: My question is, how can I correct that? I want the strlen to return 4 for ñova as well. Because of the 1 byte extra, it is corrupting the memory & misbehaving in further processing of this inout string

Comment: @Lundin I tried with wcslen but even that isn't giving the right output.

Just wrote a test program as below to test it quickly

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    char input1[] = "Café";
    char input2[] = "Привет";
    char input3[] = "ñova";

    printf("Length of input1: %d\n", strlen(input1));
    printf("Length of input2: %d\n", strlen(input2));
    printf("Length of input3: %d\n", wcslen(input3));

    return 0;
} 

I am getting the output as below

Length of input1: 5
Length of input2: 12
Length of input3: 7

Comment: @Bover don't post code in comments, as you can see it's unreadable. Instead [edit] the question and add your code _there_

Comment: @Lundin: please: do not use wchar (it is more awful), and it doesn't solve such surprise. In fact on strings made by Mac you will have different results.

Comment: @Bover look at the bytes of the `("ñova")` string with your debugger or printf thoses bytes and tell us more. Also tell us what platform you're on. Also answer the question people have asked in  the comment, preferably by [edit]ing the question

Comment: @Bover: what do you want to count? strlen is about the number of C characters (bytes). A Unicode uses codepoints for characters (small differences), and so with UTF-8 (and many other encodings) a character may have different length in bytes. But a glyph may be done by one of more codepoints (and also the same glyphs: in fact there are two canonical representation of `ñ`, on a single codepoint and one with two codepoints (so 4 bytes)), and then there are other type of text segmentation (depending on what you want). It is complex, like all human things which developed during long time.

Comment: The compiled result of source code with non-ascii characters is implementation-defined. This means (1) code with a string literal like "ñova" is not portable (2) nothing certain can be said about how to handle it without knowing the behavior (encoding) in your environment - you have to provide that information. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485801/what-characters-are-legal-to-use-in-string-literals

Comment: Why would you want it to return 4? If you are gonna work with the string, copying etc you wanna know the number of bytes not the number of glyphs.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that `strlen` returns **the count of `char`** in the string, which is not necessarily the same as the number of visible glyphs when it's printed.

The result will depend on your system's character coding - with ISO-8859.1, `"ñova"` is the same as `{ 241, 111, 118, 97, 0}` (length 4), but if you use UTF-8, for example, then `ñ` is a multi-byte character and the string is represented as `{195, 177, 111, 118, 97, 0}` (length 5).

If you want to count the number of codepoints, then you probably want to be using `mbrlen()` instead of `strlen()`.  If you want to count the number of "user" characters, taking account of combining accents and the like, then you really need a character-handling library such as ICU.

Comment: To further complicate things, `ñova` is `{195, 177, 111, 118, 97, 0}` and length 5, but `ñova` is `{110, 204, 131, 111, 118, 97, 0}` and length 6. That's because there's two ways of composing `ñ`. As you said, counting glyphs is complicated and not something found in the C standard library.