# How can I output a smile face in C-Language with XCode

Tags: c, ascii

Now I make the `for` statements as follow,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i ++) {
            printf("%5c", i);
 }
```

And I want to get the real content with ASCII

Comment: what do you mean by "real content"?

Comment: such as a smile character

Comment: I hope you know that ascii does not contain a single smile face character. So what is the actual content you want to output. The basic version of a smiley in ascii would be `:-)` or `:)`. I think there is a character from japan that looks like a smiley. In some fonts you also have smileys as a character. Any other smileys are done by showing icons instead of characters.

Comment: like this image: [img](http://imgsrc.baidu.com/forum/pic/item/5e9ad5628535e5dd3167308c74c6a7efcf1b62f6.jpg)

Comment: Those are MS-DOS OEM characters. The particular output depends on your terminal. Under Windows, run from the default command prompt, I indeed get "smile faces" (and lots of other characters) from your code, so I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Provided your terminal is set to UTF-8 encoding, this piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 char s[] = { 0xf0, 0x9f, 0x98, 0x8e, 0 };

 printf("%s", s);
}
```

outputs a [smiley with sunglasses](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f60e/index.htm).

To find out how to encode other UNICODE characters use the top navigation bar on the page (or the previous/next angle brackets)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use Unicode instead of ASCII

This's an example on Swift

```c
let dog = String(UnicodeScalar(0x1F436))
println(dog)

for codeUnit in dog.utf8 {
    print("\(codeUnit) ")
}
```

[Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I want do it in C-Language

Comment: I'm not sure about C-language, but you can use this itf8 codes of smile for input: 240 159 144 182. Actually I think it's impossible use Unicode symbols in program is written by C

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander: uh, *what*? I have been doing the impossible for some years, then. Even if you mean one cannot use *literal* Unicode characters, well, that may depend on the compiler. See e.g. [Unicode encoding for string literals in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6796157/2564301)

Comment: @Jongware yeas I meant it