# Some questions with printing output in C++

Tags: c++

When I use :

```
    std::cout << "Hello world ";
```

Which type is "Hello world" ?

Where does it stored , so I can get it out and work with it ?

For some reasons, I don't want to use something like :

```
    std::string str = "Hello world"; 
    std::cout << str;
```

Please help me, I searched an hour but still no answer.

Comment: The type of a string literal in C++ is `const char[N]`. The other parts of your question are really unclear to me.

Comment: Using `std::string str = "Hello world";` is absolutely the best way to store `"Hello world"` and do work with it.

Comment: The string constant gets placed into the data section of your compiled program. When the program is initialized, it gets loaded into memory on the heap (usually).

Comment: Also, what are "some reasons"? Why can't you declare a variable? The only thing I could think of is code golf, but if you're golfing you should probably know the language you're using better than this.

Comment: The base underlying type is `const char&`, if I'm not mistaken; a const reference to the region of memory containing the sequence of characters making up the string, terminated by a `'\0'` or NULL character. (It might be represented as a `const char*` or a `const char[N]`, I'm not sure, but the three types are *nearly* interchangeable.)

Answer (score 0):

The type of a string literal is "constant array of `char`", with as many elements as characters in the literal, plus one for a final null character. Other versions of string literals (wide, unicode) are arrays of other character types (`wchar_t`, `char16_t` etc.) (e.g. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c11)).