# The C stdio character encoding

Tags: c++, c, character-encoding

For my pet project I am experimenting with string representations, but I arrived to some troubling results. Firstly, here is a short application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
void write_to_file(FILE* fp, const char* c, size_t len)
{
    void* t = (void*)c;
    fwrite(&len, sizeof(size_t), 1, fp);
    fwrite(t, len, sizeof(char), fp);
}
int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("test.cod", "wb+");
    const char* ABCDE = "ABCDE";
    write_to_file(fp, ABCDE, strlen(ABCDE) );
    const char* nor = "BBøæåBB";
    write_to_file(fp, nor, strlen(nor));
    const char* hun = "AAőűéáöüúBB";
    write_to_file(fp, hun, strlen(hun));
    const char* per = "CCبﺙگCC";
    write_to_file(fp, per, strlen(per));
    fclose(fp);
}
```

It does nothing special, just takes in a string, and writes it's length and the string itself to a file. Now, the file, when viewed as hex, looks like:

[image: hex dump of standard char* output]

I am happy with the first result, 5 (the first 8 bytes, I'm on a 64 bit machine) as expected. However, the `nor` variable in my expectation has 7 characters (since that is what I see there), but the C library think it has `0x0A` (ie: 10) characters (second row, starting with `0A` and 8 more characters). And the string itself contains double characters (the `ø` is encoded as `C3 B8` and so on...).

The same is true for the `hun` and `per` variables.

I did the same experiment with Unicode, the following is the application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
void write_to_file(FILE* fp, const wchar_t* c, size_t len)
{
    void* t = (void*)c;
    fwrite(&len, sizeof(size_t), 1, fp);
    fwrite(t, len, sizeof(wchar_t), fp);
}

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("test.cod", "wb+");
    const wchar_t* ABCDE = L"ABCDE";
    write_to_file(fp, ABCDE, wcslen(ABCDE) );
    const wchar_t* nor = L"BBøæåBB";
    write_to_file(fp, nor, wcslen(nor));
    const wchar_t* hun = L"AAőűéáöüúBB";
    write_to_file(fp, hun, wcslen(hun));
    const wchar_t* per = L"CCبﺙگCC";
    write_to_file(fp, per, wcslen(per));
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The results here are the expected ones. 5 for the length of `ABCDE` 7 for the length of `BBøæåBB` and so on, 4 bytes per character...

[image: hex dump of whcar_t* output]

So here comes the question: what is the encoding of the standard C library, and how trustable is it when developing portable applications (ie: what I write out on a platform will be read back correctly on another one?) and what are the other recommendations taking in considerations what was presented above.

Comment: You're looking at the question the wrong way. Look at the string `nor` in the debugger before you print it. You'll see that it is 10 characters long. That's because your source file was saved in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: related: [How does file encoding affect C++11 string literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6794590/4279)

Comment: More remarkable is that this hex viewer *also* interprets UTF8 codes, rather than showing actual raw bytes. (Compare with the Unicode dump.)

Comment: @Jongware Good point.  I'm curious as to just what his environment is.  I'm not aware of any environments which support Unicode this well.

Comment: @JamesKanze the environment is a Xubuntu 12.10, the viewer is mcview, the editor I used to write the text is vi. Please ask if you're interested in more settings :) Terminal 0.4.8 - Xfce terminal emulator, LXDE desktop environment, not Xfce (yeah, it's a pretty big mess :D )

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the standard C library does *no* encoding at all.
I suppose your input file in the first case uses UTF-8 as encoding, thus your string constants will end up as UTF-8-string constants in compiled code. That is why you get the string with a length of 10 chars.

`fwrite` takes an (untyped) byte array as argument. Since it does not know anything about the bytes processed, it cannot do any encoding-conversion at all here.

Regarding portability, you should be more careful about things like pointer lengths. `fwrite(&len, sizeof(size_t), 1, fp)`can yield different results on different platforms, maybe causing your file to be read incorrectly. Also (especially with multi-byte encodings) you have to be careful with the platform's endianness.

For anything else, you can be sure, that your standard library will put the bytes to disk exactly as you pass them, but when processing them as text, you have to make sure that you use the same encoding on all platforms.

Comment: The standard C library *does* have to do encoding on platforms like Windows that operate in UTF-16 internally.

Comment: @dan04 Ok, but this relates to things like Console-I/O, I guess?

Comment: Also to things like `fopen`.

Comment: @dan04 I did not know this before. Thank you for the information, but is this a MS extension of the standard?

Comment: It's not an extension.  It's how functions from the standard library have to be *implemented* when C's execution character set is different from the encoding that the OS uses to store filenames.

MSVC++ does provide extensions like `_wfopen` that allow the developer to pass UTF-16 strings directly.  It's *necessary* to use these functions on Windows because otherwise you can't straightforwardly open a file whose name contains characters outside the ANSI code page.

Comment: @dan04 Are you actually talking about the encoding of the filename? I meant the `css` extension, found in MSDN reference to fopen. Filenames have to be converted, of course, no question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43636/discussion-between-dan04-and-user1781290)

Answer (score 3):

There is no real answer to your question.  Practically everything involving encoding is implementation dependent, and often locale dependent as well.  Judging from appearances, your narrow character encoding is Unicode UTF-8, and your wide character encoding is Unicode UTF-32LE.  This is far from universal, however; even today, I suspect that the most widespread narrow character encoding is ISO 8859-1, and there are still machines which use EBCDIC.  For wide character encodings, both UTF-16 and UTF-32 are widespread, and some machines still use older encodings as well.  (If you use C++ style IO, you can embed a specific encoding in the stream itself.)

As for your code, `fwrite` doesn't know (or care) that it is dealing with characters.  It just copies an image of memory out to disk (which makes it pretty useless, except for sequences of pre-formatted bytes, since such images generally can't be reliably read back in).

As for `strlen`: it doesn't know about multibyte characters; it returns the number of *bytes* until the first 0 byte, not the number of characters.  The number of bytes is likely to be superior to the number of characters for any multibyte encoding format.  But the issue is even more complex.  Independently of the encoding format, there are cases where a sequence of more than one code point will result in a single character; e.g. `"\u0063\u0302"` will represent a single character, although functions like `strlen` or `wcslen` (assuming a wide character string literal) will report more.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C Library does not encode anything.

If you need portability, it is better to handle then encoding explicitly. libiconv and libicu both work well. You only need to convert data to a certain encoding, for example UTF8, then save the string to disk using fwrite().

You should also use char not wchar_t, because wchar_t is at least 16 bits, which may lead to endianess problem on a different platform.

As for strlen(), it is designed to be used with ANSI string, to determine a string of wchar_t, you should use wcslen() (if available) instead. otherwise, it is better to use explicit conversion on strings.

Answer (score 0):

As our collegues pointed out, `fwrite` does not know about the encoding.

First, take a serius looking at this link, it is has a great overview of encodings:

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

If you don´t want to use any external libs you will have to deal with your strings in a low level manner.

For instance, if you are sure about using wchar_t (e.g., expecting UTF-16 encoding), an approach is to resize the `len` passed to `write_to_file` according to platform size of `wchar_t`, so `fwrite` will write the correct number of bytes.

Like this:

```
write_to_file(fp, ABCDE, sizeof(wchar_t)*wcslen(ABCDE) );
```

You have 5 wchar_t´s, but in Windows/MingGW each of then is 2 bytes long.

Remember to consider the BOM ([Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) when dealing with UTF-16. It can be valuable to get bytes in the right order.

Encodings like UTF-8 has a strictly more complex approach if you want to deal with it (take a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)), and maybe using a out-of-the-shelf lib can be a good idea. I don´t have extensive experience on UTF-8 over C++ and I´ll let the collegues indicate a good lib!

To finalize, take a look in new strings that arrived at C++11:

[u32string](http://v2.cplusplus.com/reference/string/u32string/) and 
[u16string](http://v2.cplusplus.com/reference/string/u16string/)

That can be helpful to guarantee character size.

(and don´t forget the old [wstring](http://v2.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/), but as usual you wchat_t if platform dependent )